# How do I modify a category page on a wordpress site using the X theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[Here](http://linq.mit.edu/category/news/) is the site in question. I want to change the title from "category archive" to news.

According to this article (community.theme.co/forums/topic/custom-category-pages/) I need to create a file called "category-news.php" in the child theme. My issue is that I have no idea what to put in that file.

According to the template hierarchy laid out in [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates), the news page should be using "index.php" as its template file. Index.php reads

```
<?php x_get_view( x_get_stack(), 'wp', 'index' ); ?>
```

Essentially my issue is that I have no idea what the content of category-news.php should be if I want to change the title. And I don't even really understand where the current title is coming from.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Copy the category.php file of your theme in the child theme folder, rename it in your child theme folder to category-news.php and change the title in the category-news.php file, thats all you have to do.

Comment: @JavierGonzalez I do not see a file called category.php in the X-theme files.

Comment: I dont know this theme, you have to find out which template file is responsible for view of the page and follow the instructions in my first comment

Answer (score 1):

I spend an hour trying to find this template in X Theme. So an answer might still be relevant, even though the question is quite old.

**1. Solution — If you just need to change the text**

You can change the headline and description from the Categories section in the WordPress admin.
X Theme adds a few extra input fields named "Archive Title" and "Archive Subtitle" and you can type in whatever name you like.

*Have a look at the ThemeCo forum: https://theme.co/apex/forums/topic/category-archive-page/*

**2. Solution — Edit the template ( PHP and HTML )**

The template is called `_landmark-header.php` - but the placement is far from obvious and the directory changes depending on the X Theme stack you are using. e.g ethos, icon, integrity or renew. 
This can be echoed or dumped with the `x_get_stack()` function.

The full path to the template file is;

```
wp-content/themes/x/framework/legacy/cranium/headers/views/*stack name*/_landmark-header.php
```

This file can be overwritten from your child theme, if you copy the file and replicate the folder structure in your child theme. e.g

```
wp-content/themes/*x-child*/framework/legacy/cranium/headers/views/*stack name*/_landmark-header.php
```

*Be aware that this looks like a legacy template, so it might not work with future theme updates.*